# Measure AC (24VAC) current with 3.3 MCU

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, current-measurement, esp8266, esp32

I'm trying to use the following circuit designed by someone else :

[image]

VCC = 3.3V

It's aparently adapted from this one:

[image]

Taken from : https://github.com/OpenSprinkler/OpenSprinkler-Hardware/tree/master/OS/3.0/AC_driver

In the original design a esp8266 with a 10-bit resolution ADC is used, in the derived design a ESP32 with a resolution of 12-bit is used.

I'm trying to use the first design to measure the AC voltage on ACRET and convert it to current with the following code:

```
uint32_t read_ac_current(void)
{
    const int SAMPLE_COUNT = 20;
    uint32_t adc_reading = 0;

    float r5 = 100800.0f; // R5 in ohm, 100k
    float r6 = 2016000.0f; // R6 in ohm, 2M

    adc1_config_width(ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12);
    adc1_config_channel_atten(ADC1_CHANNEL_6, ADC_ATTEN_11db);

    for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < SAMPLE_COUNT; ++sampleIndex)
    {
        adc_reading += adc1_get_raw(ADC1_CHANNEL_6);
        vTaskDelay(5 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    }

    /* calculate the average value from the 20 readings */
    adc_reading /= SAMPLE_COUNT;

    /* calculate voltage */
    float voltage = ((3.3f * adc_reading) / 4095.0f);

    /* Calculate current */
    float current = voltage * (r5 / (r5 + r6));

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "current -> raw : %d, voltage : %f V, current : %f A", adc_reading, voltage, current);

    return current;
}
```

and getting:

```
I (40790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 126, voltage : 0.101538 V, current : 0.004835 A
I (42790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 100, voltage : 0.080586 V, current : 0.003837 A
I (44790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 100, voltage : 0.080586 V, current : 0.003837 A
I (46790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 102, voltage : 0.082198 V, current : 0.003914 A
I (48790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 101, voltage : 0.081392 V, current : 0.003876 A
    I (88790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 101, voltage : 0.081392 V, current : 0.003876 A
I (90790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 100, voltage : 0.080586 V, current : 0.003837 A
I (92790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 98, voltage : 0.078974 V, current : 0.003761 A
I (94790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 99, voltage : 0.079780 V, current : 0.003799 A
I (96790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 100, voltage : 0.080586 V, current : 0.003837 A
I (98790) SMART_HUERTO: current -> raw : 100, voltage : 0.080586 V, current : 0.003837 A
```

The current measure is far from the results I am expecting :

- A)Is the formula for calculating the current OK?
- B)What's the point of D3 and D4 in the first design?
- C)Why the value R6(in first design) is so different to RS on the original design? 0.2 vs 200M

Comment: R6 = 200m **(NOT 2M!)**; `float r6 = 0.2f;`

Comment: There's also no obvious reason why you'd do these calculations in floating point.

Comment: Also (correct me if I'm wrong) I don't think R5+R6 is meant to be a voltage divider. R6 is the current sense "shunt" resistor which is the relevant one, R5 is just there to protect the OP (can it handle currents that small though?).

Comment: @Seir ups, you are right, this is the resistor https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Chip-Resistor-Surface-Mount_Uniroyal-Elec-25121WF200LT4E_C83749.html its 200m

Comment: @Lundin, if R6 is used as shunt resistor how sould I convert voltage at ACRET to current?

Comment: @Marc Ohm's law? I'm not quite sure how this circuit works though, why not use a specialized current sense OP?

Comment: Have you tried using a power supply in place of ACRET and measuring the output voltage of your circuit with a meter? Have you tried the code with a variable power supply voltage in place of the circuit? You should isolate the problem to either the circuit or the code.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit (first picture) does not really work?

[image]

Without the diode of the second circuit, this work (except for "low" current).

[image]

Comment: In theory it should work, the circuit was designed by someone else and I'm trying to write the software for it, when I add 24vac loads the voltage rise proportionally at ACRET, I now have to convert this voltage to current consumption